# Minikube reports "Authentication is required" for 1 out of 20 images

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Okay, so I have a Minikube setup and deploying a Helm chart. This chart pulls mainly from one repo where I need to authenticate.

I do a `kubectl create secret` for that repo and most of the images are pulling fine. Just one (always the same) doesn't get pulled with an error `Authentication is required`.

How can I find out why this exact image is failing and all others from the same repo (same authentication and everything) work fine?

BTW: When I do a `docker login` and `docker pull` *inside* of the Minikube container everything works fine as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error shows the image `requires authentication`, the image might be a **private image**. To resolve this issue, you can create a pull secret using the `“kubectl create secret docker-registry”` command and add it to your service account’s list of pull secrets or add it directly to the deployment using the `“imagePullSecrets”` list.

Apply your secret to your cluster using Kubectl:

```
Kubectl apply -f image-pull-secret.yaml
```

And now you must update your pod’s manifest to instruct Kubernetes to use the created secret when fetching the image

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
Metadata:
    name: example
Spec:
    Containers:
       - name: example
        image: registry.example.com/example-image:latest
    imagePullSecrets:
       - name: image-pull-secret
```

Apply the updated pod manifest to your cluster. The next pull attempt should now succeed. Kubernetes will be able to authenticate to the registry and download the image.

Beware that variations of the `pull access denied` error may also appear when you’re using authentication but specifying an invalid username or password. In this case, you should check the pod’s `imagePullSecrets` to make sure it’s referencing the correct secret.

You can refer to the documents written by [Austin Dawey](https://austindewey.com/2020/07/20/is-your-kubernetes-pod-failing-to-start-heres-a-command-to-get-back-on-your-feet/) and [James walker](https://www.datree.io/resources/kubernetes-error-codes-failed-to-pull-image) for more information on troubleshooting imagePullSecrets.

Comment: I was indeed stupid enough to forget to add the `imagePullSecrets` to this one container. I changed the container from a public to a private image and forgot to add this entry.
Sorry for the bother and thanks for re-triggering me checking that all containers have their `imagePullSecrets` configured.